# Jackson throwing the invalid access for the schema validation

Tags: java, jboss

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.DEFAULT_ROOT_VALUE_SEPARATOR from class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactoryBuilder 
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactoryBuilder.<init>(JsonFactoryBuilder.java:36) 
    at io.swagger.v3.parser.ObjectMapperFactory.createJsonFactory(ObjectMapperFactory.java:41) 
    at io.swagger.v3.parser.ObjectMapperFactory.createJson(ObjectMapperFactory.java:18) 
    at io.swagger.v3.parser.ObjectMapperFactory.createJson(ObjectMapperFactory.java:14) 
    at io.swagger.v3.parser.OpenAPIV3Parser.<clinit>(OpenAPIV3Parser.java:43) at io.swagger.parser.OpenAPIParser.readContents(OpenAPIParser.java:28) 
    at com.atlassian.oai.validator.util.OpenApiLoader.readSwaggerParserResult(OpenApiLoader.java:63) 
    at com.atlassian.oai.validator.util.OpenApiLoader.loadApi(OpenApiLoader.java:46) 
    at com.atlassian.oai.validator.OpenApiInteractionValidator$Builder.build(OpenApiInteractionValidator.java:606)
```

**tried the dependency tree. mvn dependecy:tree**

/- com.atlassian.oai:swagger-request-validator-core:jar:2.18.0:compile [INFO] | +- io.swagger.parser.v3:swagger-parser:jar:2.0.29:compile [INFO] | | +- io.swagger.parser.v3:swagger-parser-v2-converter:jar:2.0.29:compile [INFO] | | | +- io.swagger:swagger-core:jar:1.6.3:compile [INFO] | | | | - io.swagger:swagger-models:jar:1.6.3:compile [INFO] | | | | - io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.6.3:compile [INFO] | | | +- io.swagger:swagger-parser:jar:1.0.56:compile [INFO] | | | +- io.swagger:swagger-compat-spec-parser:jar:1.0.56:compile [INFO] | | | | - com.github.java-json-tools:json-patch:jar:1.13:compile [INFO] | | | +- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-models:jar:2.1.11:compile [INFO] | | | - io.swagger.parser.v3:swagger-parser-core:jar:2.0.29:compile [INFO] | | - io.swagger.parser.v3:swagger-parser-v3:jar:2.0.29:compile [INFO] | | - io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-core:jar:2.1.11:compile [INFO] | | +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.2:compile [INFO] | | | - jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.1:compile [INFO] | | +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.15.0-rc2:compile [INFO] | | +- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations:jar:2.1.11:compile [INFO] | | - jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.2:compile/

**is it due to the dependency conflict?**

Comment: Are you using WildFly or JBoss EAP? If so which version?

Comment: `jboss-eap-7.1`

Comment: If you're including Jackson in your deployment there is a chance it's conflicting with the version provided by JBoss EAP 7.1. You may want to try to exclude Jackson from your deployment.

Comment: `Thanks it worked`